# Accidentally deleted a module needed by yum - how to reinstall it?

Tags: python, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

I have a problem when trying to update yum. It gives me an error:

```
After running yum update

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named base64

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:36:13)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I may have accidentally deleted the base64 module when I was trying to remove another module.

1. Is there a way to reinstall the base64 module?
2. Is there a way to reinstall python2.6 for Red Hat?

Note that the base64 module is missing, and hence `yum` doesn't work.

(Suggestion from Nikolay) Tried installing the RPM packages:
python-devel-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm
python-libs-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm

```
rpm -ivh --force *
warning: python-devel-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
warning: python-libs-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:python-libs            ########################################### [ 50%]
   2:python-devel      

 ########################################### [100%]
```

python:

```
import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 92, in <module>
    import base64
ImportError: No module named base64
```

Still showing base64, a python module missing.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5001536/1418463) explains how to install Python in Linux without yum.

Comment: Nikolay Thanks I've tried that; however that doesn't replace the existing Python 2.6 which Yum is dependent on. I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: Ok. Did you see [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=22146) ?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Getting this:root@jaws# /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.6.6
root@jaws# rpm -qf /usr/bin/python
python-2.6.6-36.el6.i686      Which I believe means same version, so it's not a python mismatch?

Comment: probably it is not. But anyway, that guy had a very similar problem and he resolved that in [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=22146#p104055). I would try it, because it does make sense what he did.

Comment: @ Nikolay... you were right! it fixed it. All I had to do was install python-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm, did "rpm -i --forced python-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm".  my module is back up and running, Yum works and python is working! Please supply as an answer so I can check answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solves by installing Python rpm package as follows:

```
rpm -i --forced python-2.6.6-36.el6.i686.rpm
```

This brings all missing Python modules back so that Python is operational again.